# OOP design: How to decide program flow and class responsible for method (JSFML library)

Tags: java, oop, drawable, sfml, program-flow

I'm designing a 2D game to practice Java and Object Oriented Programming (I'm using the JSFML library, if that helps), and I have doubts regarding how to best design the following:

The library I'm using offers a `Drawable` interface implemented by visible game elements (the player, enemies, backgrounds, etc). I also have a `RenderWindow` upon which I'll draw the `Drawable` objects.

Here's the thing, the `RenderWindow` has a `draw(Drawable d)` method that draws a `Drawable` object on the current Window, and the `Drawable` objects have a `draw(RenderWindow r)` method that draws the current `Drawable` object on the `RenderWindow` passed.

If they do basically the same thing, which one should I use? Why? What should I take into consideration to decide? I use a HashMap to store the `Drawable` objects. Should I pass the `RenderWindow` to the `Drawables` in the HashMap or pass the `Drawables` in the HashMap to the `RenderWindow`? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line answer to your question would be
**Java language does not support double dispatch mechanism.**
**What to do:** The library expects you to override these methods but never call them. I haven't used the library but from some experience with game engines, I guess the application will call the RenderWindow's draw and it will eventually make calls to all Drawable's draw methods. (Collection of Drawables will be maintained by RenderWindow.
**Why:** Java dynamically calls the method by checking the class of object on which the method being called (not by checking reference). This is called (as you probably know) dynamic dispatch.
But the method's arguments are selected by only checking reference (not by class of  actual object passed as argument.)
*Here, by forcing dynamic dispatch twice (by making two methods for same purpose), the library developers have indirectly implemented double dispatch.*
In future, you might want to extend both Drawable and RenderWindow. If you had draw method in only Drawable, you can't have separate draw for each child of RenderWindow. Double dispatch solves this problem.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get it, why should I override the methods? RenderWindow.draw(Drawable d) has a working implementation (and Drawable is implemented by Sprite, another library class, I didn't mention it to keep the question simpler, thought it didn't matter). The library (JSFML) is essentially a wrapper for a C++ library, if this makes any difference.

Comment: RenderWindow will have a standard implementation which you would override in only extremely rare cases. Drawable's method has to be overridden. But as you have pointed out, library gives a reference implementation (Sprite) (But sometimes you need your own, say AnimatedSprite). So you just have to add Sprites to RenderWindow in most simple cases. (Which is the purpose of having a library, almost everything already implemented). I was just trying to explain the design considerations by library developers which may not be immediately required by end user.